# ggplot GLM fitted curve without interaction

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, glm, interaction

I want to add the fitted function from GLM on a `ggplot`. By default, it automatically create the plot with interaction. I am wondering, if I can plot the fitted function from the model without interaction. For example,

```
dta <- read.csv("http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/data/poisson_sim.csv")
dta <- within(dta, {
  prog <- factor(prog, levels=1:3, labels=c("General", "Academic", "Vocational"))
  id <- factor(id)
})

plt <- ggplot(dta, aes(math, num_awards, col = prog)) + 
    geom_point(size = 2) + 
    geom_smooth(method = "glm", , se = F, 
        method.args = list(family = "poisson"))

print(plt)
```

gives the plot with interaction, [image: Fig-1]

However, I want the plot from the model,

```
`num_awards` = ß0 + ß1*`math` + ß2*`prog` + error
```

I tried to get this this way,

```
mod <- glm(num_awards ~ math + prog, data = dta, family = "poisson")

fun.gen <- function(awd) exp(mod$coef[1] + mod$coef[2] * awd)
fun.acd <- function(awd) exp(mod$coef[1] + mod$coef[2] * awd + mod$coef[3])
fun.voc <- function(awd) exp(mod$coef[1] + mod$coef[2] * awd + mod$coef[4])

ggplot(dta, aes(math, num_awards, col = prog)) +
    geom_point() +
    stat_function(fun = fun.gen, col = "red") +
    stat_function(fun = fun.acd, col = "green") +
    stat_function(fun = fun.voc, col = "blue") +
    geom_smooth(method = "glm", se = F, 
        method.args = list(family = "poisson"), linetype = "dashed")
```

The output plot is [image: Fig2]

Is there any simple way in `ggplot` to do this efficiently?

Answer (score 6):

Ben's idea of plotting predicted value of the response for specific model terms inspired me improving the `type = "y.pc"` option of the `sjp.glm` function. A new update is [on GitHub](https://github.com/sjPlot/devel), with version number 1.9.4-3.

Now you can plot predicted values for specific terms, one which is used along the x-axis, and a second one used as grouping factor:

```
sjp.glm(mod, type = "y.pc", vars = c("math", "prog"))
```

which gives you following plot:

[image]

The `vars` argument is needed in case your model has more than two terms, to specify the term for the x-axis-range and the term for the grouping.

You can also facet the groups:

```
sjp.glm(mod, type = "y.pc", vars = c("math", "prog"), show.ci = T, facet.grid = T)
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

There's no way that I know of to trick `geom_smooth()` into doing this, but you can do a *little* better than you've done. You still have to fit the model yourself and add the lines, but you can use the `predict()` method to generate the predictions and load them into a data frame with the same structure as the original data ...

```
mod <- glm(num_awards ~ math + prog, data = dta, family = "poisson")
## generate prediction frame
pframe <- with(dta,
             expand.grid(math=seq(min(math),max(math),length=51),
                         prog=levels(prog)))
## add predicted values (on response scale) to prediction frame
pframe$num_awards <- predict(mod,newdata=pframe,type="response")

ggplot(dta, aes(math, num_awards, col = prog)) +
   geom_point() +
   geom_smooth(method = "glm", se = FALSE,
       method.args = list(family = "poisson"), linetype = "dashed")+
   geom_line(data=pframe)  ## use prediction data here
          ## (inherits aesthetics etc. from main ggplot call)
```

(the only difference here is that the way I've done it the predictions span the full horizontal range for all groups, as if you had specified `fullrange=TRUE` in `geom_smooth()`).

In principle it seems as though the [sjPlot package](https://cran.r-project.org/package=sjPlot) should be able to handle this sort of thing, but it looks like the relevant bit of code for doing this plot type is hard-coded to assume a binomial GLM ...  oh well.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure, but you wrote "without interaction" - maybe you are looking for effect plots? (If not, excuse me that I'm assuming something completely wrong...)

You can, for instance, use the [effects package](https://cran.r-project.org/package=effects) for this.

```
dta <- read.csv("http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/data/poisson_sim.csv")
dta <- within(dta, {
  prog <- factor(prog, levels=1:3, labels=c("General", "Academic", "Vocational"))
  id <- factor(id)
})

mod <- glm(num_awards ~ math + prog, data = dta, family = "poisson")

library(effects)
plot(allEffects(mod))
```

[image]

Another option would be the sjPlot package, as Ben suggested - however, the current version on CRAN only supports logistic regression models properly for effect plots. But in the current development version on [GitHub](https://github.com/sjPlot/devel) I added support for various model families and link functions, so if you like, you can download that snapshot. The sjPlot package uses ggplot instead of lattice (which is used by the effects package, I think):

```
sjp.glm(mod, type = "eff", show.ci = T)
```

[image]

Or in non-faceted way:

```
sjp.glm(mod, type = "eff", facet.grid = F, show.ci = T)
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: thanks, but I don't think this quite does what the OP wants.  "without interaction" means they want to plot the predictions of an additive (`~math+prog`) model ...

Comment: Ok, than your answer looks like the shortest way to get the plot. "Without interactions" and `num_awards = ß0 + ß1*math + ß2*prog + error` looked to me like marginal effects was the thing the OP was looking for.

Comment: ... I tried `sjp.glm(mod,type="y.pc",axisLabels="math")`, which is I think what the OP wants, with sjPlot version 1.9.4.2 (fresh from Github, unless I screwed up) and got a blank plot and a warning message ...

Comment: This plot-type sets the axis limits from 0 to 1 (assuming binomial GLM), so you just found the one plot-type that was not fixed to match different model families ;-) Anyway, this function would not exactly do this, because the x-axis are just values from 1 to `nrow`. I don't know how to handle response-predictions in a generic way. What, if the model had even more covariates, or only continuous covariates? Then I would not know which terms to choose as grouping factor. Honestly, currently the type-option `y.pc` is not doing much useful things.