# Plotting two curves with poisson glm with interactions in categorical variable

Tags: r, plot, glm, poisson

I want to know if is possible to plotting two curves with poisson glm with interactions in categorical variables. In my case:

```
##Data set artificial
set.seed(20)
d <- data.frame(
    behv = c(rpois(100,10),rpois(100,100)),
    mating=sort(rep(c("T1","T2"), 200)),
    condition = scale(rnorm(200,5))
) 

#Binomial GLM ajusted
model<-glm(behv ~ mating + condition, data=d, family=poisson)
summary(model)
```

In a situation where mating (categorical) and condition (numeric) are significant in the model

```
newdata <- d
newdata$condition <- mean(d$condition)
newdata$yhat <- predict(model, newdata, type = "response")
newdata <- newdata[order(newdata$mating),]
plot(newdata$behv~newdata$condition,ylab=c("behv"),
xlab=c("condition"),xlim=c(-3,3))
lines(x = newdata$mating, y = newdata$yhat)
```

Doesn't work and I've like a curve for T1 and other curve for T2 in mating variable and 
changes is given by condition variable in the plot. I will try to use coefficients selection for each level of mating variable, but doesn't work too. Any ideas?

Comment: If you want `ggplot2` see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36459967/ggplot-glm-fitted-curve-without-interaction).

Comment: What exactly does "doesn't work" mean in this case? What is the expected output supposed to be? "Any ideas?" isn't a very specific question.