# Plot Poisson Multiple Regression with Interaction

Tags: r, ggplot2, glm, poisson

I am new to working with generalized linear models and I'm having trouble plotting the results of a glm call with ggplot. My data contains only continuous variables: one response variable (count data - continuous) and two explanatory variables (both continuous). So, I am conducting a poisson multiple regression. I have found some examples of how to plot data and to fit the curve regarding normally distributed data. I have also found here ([ggplot GLM fitted curve without interaction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36459967/ggplot-glm-fitted-curve-without-interaction)) an example of how to plot and fit a poisson ANCOVA model. In such a case, the explanatory variables are one categorical and one continuous, so it does not work for me.

I have data that look like this:

```
df<-data.frame( 
  p1=c(230.2, 110.1, 90.5, 100.3, 110.0, 380.4,  80.5,  60.7, 250.8, 350.2),
  resp=c(31, 28, 12, 28, 18, 48, 19, 25, 28, 18),
  p2=c(48,  36,  12, 168,  12,  60,  18,  39,  60,  12))
```

I ran a model as follows:

```
m <- glm(resp ~ p1*p2, family = poisson, data=df)

anova(m, test="Chi")
```

It returned me this:

```
Analysis of Deviance Table

Model: poisson, link: log

Response: resp

Terms added sequentially (first to last)


      Df Deviance Resid. Df Resid. Dev Pr(>Chi)   
NULL                      9     33.204            
p1     1   9.9623         8     23.242 0.001598 **
p2     1   7.2787         7     15.963 0.006978 **
p1:p2  1   7.7652         6      8.198 0.005326 **
```

So, there is an interaction between the explanatory variables (p1 and p2). My question is: how can I plot the results of this glm call using geom_smooth in ggplot, so that I can fit the curve and show the interaction between the two continuous explanatory variables? In addition, is there a better way to plot and visualize that?